# Integration problem $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \sin^n 2x\cos^n3x \, dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

This is the problem I'm trying to solve: Find $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \sin^n 2x \cos^n 3x \, dx$.

For $n=0$ we get $\frac{\pi}{2}$,

for $n=1$ we have $$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \sin2x\cos3x \, dx = \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\sin5x-\sin x}{2} \, dx= \left.\frac{-\frac{\cos5x}{5}+\cos x}{2}\right|_0^\frac{\pi}{2}=-\frac{2}{5},$$
for larger $n$, more computation is needed...

It seemed to me that this could be solved by partial integration (in order to get some recursive formula), but I didn't managed to solve it.

Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Any hint is welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: A kind of unpleasant integral. You may exploit De Moivre's formula and the binomial theorem to write it as a weigthed sum of binomial coefficients, but the asymptotic behaviour is just given by the behaviour of $\sin(2x)\cos(3x)$ over $(0,\pi/2)=(0,\pi/6]\cup[\pi/6,\pi/2)$, whose absolute value is bounded by $0.907858\ldots < 1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can write the integral in terms of a finite sum of the Beta function. We have $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{n}\left(2x\right)\cos^{n}\left(3x\right)dx=2^{n}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{n}\left(x\right)\cos^{2n}\left(x\right)\left(2\cos\left(2x\right)-1\right)^{n}dx
 $$ $$=2^{n}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{n}\left(x\right)\cos^{2n}\left(x\right)\left(2\cos^{2}\left(x\right)-2\sin^{2}\left(x\right)-1\right)^{n}dx
 $$ $$=2^{n}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{n}\left(x\right)\cos^{2n}\left(x\right)\left(4\cos^{2}\left(x\right)-3\right)^{n}dx
 $$ $$=2^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}4^{k}\left(-3\right)^{n-k}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{n}\left(x\right)\cos^{2n+2k}\left(x\right)dx
 $$ 
$$\color{red}{=2^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}4^{k}\left(-3\right)^{n-k}B\left(\frac{n+1}{2},n+k+\frac{1}{2}\right).}$$
**Addendum:** Note that using this method we can easily generalize the result for the integral $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{n}\left(2x\right)\cos^{m}\left(3x\right)dx,\, m,n\geq1.$$

Comment: Nice answer. It might be useful to simplify the final result for even $n$ versus odd $n$, since that determines whether or not the first argument is integer or half-integer.